# Swift access binding from another struct

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm new to swift so sorry if this question is confusing, I'm not 100% sure I'm even asking the right question. I'm loosely following [this](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-macos-app) guide for creating a macOS app with objects in a sidebar. Unlike in that tutorial I'm using Coredata to store the objects, and I also started on macOS as opposed to expanding the app to work on macOS, but I don't think that should matter.

I'm on section 6, trying to create a binding for the selected sidebar element so I can use it for menu commands. However since I'm using Coredata instead of the data model that they're using, I'm not sure how to go about it. I got a binding to work storing the index of the selected item, as opposed to the actual object, like in the guide. However I would prefer to do it how it's done in the guide (the reason I did it the other way is I want to set a default selection in the sidebar, and I couldn't figure out how to do it this way), and I can't figure out how to get it to work with menu commands.

Here is my SwiftUI code that gets the data from Coredata and displays it, and includes the binding (The way I have it implemented using the index):

```
struct InstanceList: View {
    @State var selectedInstanceIndex: Int? = 0
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Instance.entity(),
        sortDescriptors:
            [
                NSSortDescriptor(
                    keyPath: \Instance.userOrder,
                    ascending: true),
                NSSortDescriptor(
                    keyPath:\Instance.name,
                    ascending: true )
            ]
    ) private var instances: FetchedResults<Instance>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(Array(zip(instances.indices, instances)), id: \.0) { index, instance in
                    NavigationLink(destination: InstanceView(instance: instance), tag: index, selection: $selectedInstanceIndex) {
                        InstanceRow(instance: instance)
                    }
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Instances")
            .frame(minWidth: 150)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Some other unrelated code is down here
}
```

So how would I change the binding to store an Instance object the way it stores a Landmark in the tutorial, be able to set a default selection in the sidebar, and then access the binding in another struct so I can set up menu commands?

Hopefully this made sense...

Thanks!